# How to Iterate ModelBuilder for Zonal Statistics?

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, zonal-statistics, iterator

I want to use ModelBuilder to split a DEM into multiple tiles, then run the iterator on each tile made for the Zonal Statistics tool to find the highest point(s) in each tile and give these as an output.

Each time I try this ModelBuilder crashes.

Any suggestions/ ideas on how to make my model run?

Comment: Why do you need to split the DEM?  There are plenty of alternative (and much more efficient ways) to solve this problem, depending on whether the tiles overlap or not.  If they don't overlap, only one zonal stats command is needed anyway.  If you really want to make your particular model run, regardless, you will need to edit this question to provide enough information to let people help you figure out what's going wrong: "crashes" is not enough to go on.